# PhoneGap / Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, ember.js

I have Application that is Ember for client and MVC.net for server.

Application is severely coupled, meaning client is deeply integrated in with the server.

My requirement is to be able to run the client in the Phonegap and build the Android version of the program and simply call the REST end points from the server.

Reading PhoneGap documentation, I have seen that PhoneGap requires cleanly separated applications, meaning that Client requires index.html file in order to be successfully ported to Android.

1. Do I really need index file for my application, is there some trick that I can point phone gap to build the application? VS that I have  solution contains Scripts folder that contains Ember script files (MVC folder structure). Can phone gap do it? Or do I need to manually separate it, make sure it runs on its own and then port it to phonegap.
2. If I build it with phone gap, phonegap will create directory with freshly built application... but do I get source files that can be edited within Eclipse?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Its Phonegap not phoneGapa.

Comment: Corrected the typo. Thank you